# Backend delete method failing to delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have lately been having trouble with some code I've been writing, specifically with the portions for deleting an User's Booking of an Hotel. When I click the toggleable button on the Hotel component, it will trigger one of two different functions, depending if the logged-in User has already booked at the Hotel (which triggers my `deleteBooking` function) or not (which triggers my `postBooking` function).  For some reason, (I *think*) my `set_booking` method isn't working.  Checking my `http://localhost:3001/users/${currentUser.id}/bookings` URL, all of the bookings are there (my POST request is working, so no problems there), *but* my `http://localhost:3001/users/${currentUser.id}/bookings/${bookingId}` URL, the only thing I get returned is `null`, and my console keeps returning *only* `DELETE http://localhost:3001/users/8/bookings/1 500 (Internal Server Error)`.  My version of `postgresql` is 1.1.

I've already tried using `debugger` and `byebug` along the entire flow of this portion of my code (and immediately after it), as well as changing the variables being used.

bookings_controller.rb:

```
skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create, :destroy]

def destroy
        # byebug
        set_booking
        byebug
        render json: @booking
        byebug 
        @booking.destroy
        byebug
    end

private
def set_booking
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    # render json: @booking
    byebug
end

def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:hotel_id, :user_id, :id)
end
```

Hotel.jsx:

```
function toggleBooking(e){
console.log("e.target: ", e.target.id);
if(booked === true){
  const booking = bookings.find(booking => {return booking.hotel.id == e.target.id});
  console.log("Booking.id: ", booking.id);
  deleteBookings(booking.id);
  setBooked(!booked);
} else if(booked === false){
  postBookings();
  setBooked(!booked);
}

console.log("Your Bookings: ", bookings);}




function deleteBookings(bookingId){
fetch(`http://localhost:3001/users/${currentUser.id}/bookings/${bookingId}`, {
  method: "DELETE"
})
.then((r) => {
  if(r.ok)onDeleteBookings(bookings.id);
})}

function onDeleteBookings(deletedBooking){
const updatedBookings = bookings.filter((booking) => booking.id !== deletedBooking.id);
setBookings(updatedBookings);}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?  And will you need the repo link?

Comment: I am not following the code, but generally when a DELETE does not happen after a DELETE statement it is because the action was done in a transaction that was not committed.

Comment: Okay, so for some reason, when I follow the route for the bookings DELETE request in my 'http://localhost:3001/rails/info/routes' (which would be '/users/:user_id/bookings/:id(.:format)'), all I ever get back is "null".  I have put *byebugs* into my backend, and every time, the last byebug to go off is the one inside of my '*set_booking*' method, which leads me to believe that that has something to do with the problem.  However, I am unsure of how to fix it.  I also tried to keep the code snippets as short as I could, so please let me know if you need the repository link.

Comment: I see that your render in the delete action happens before you delete the booking. Then your booking is never deleted. But if you have an error 500 there may be another problem. Check that your action dleete is indeed used with a delete method. Usually you get all information in the Puma logs.

Comment: I have just gotten rid of the render in there, and it does delete now, but only after refreshing the page. I'm not sure why...  maybe it is because of my toggleBooking function...?

Comment: You make your call async, with a fetch. Page refreshes shouldn't come into play. What I am sure is that the record is deleted when this action is hit. Do you rather mean "deleted on screen" ? then I guess it is the role of your JSX to delete the booking on screen. Or maybe put back the render after you have destroyed the record ? so something is returned to React?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to delete it on screen.  Right now, I am still working on displaying it on another page.

Comment: Okay, the problem is fixed now, it turned out to be an issue with the params in the controller.